# CSRF issue while saving data in .net

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, csrf, .net-4.5

When I create form in mvc using beginform and antiforgery token and  also with validate antiforgery token on controller, but when I save data and locally store the `_requestverificationtoken` then I again form the submit and replace the current token value to previous then save it it also save but when I used antiforgery tags why it is submit.

```
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.Hidden("PaneName", null)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Task_Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Button)
                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Task Details <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5, @cols = 60, @style = "max-width:65% !important;" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Additional Comments</label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Additional_Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5, @cols = 60, @style = "max-width:65% !important;" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@

                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Review Date <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Review_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Review Date" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Review_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Weightage(%) <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weightage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Weightage" , onkeypress = "return isNumber(event)"} })

                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Task Assigned By </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-2">

                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.TaskAssignBy)

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Task Assign To <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">

                                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_js, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_JS, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "ddljs", @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem_js, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedItem_js, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                                    <br />
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_dir, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_DIR, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddldir", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_ds, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_DS, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlds", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_section_officer, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_SECTION_OFF, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlsecoff", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_psu, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_PSU, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlpsu", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_JS, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddljs", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_DIR, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddldir", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_DS, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddlds", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_SECTION_OFF, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddlsecoff", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_PSU, "PSU_CODE", "NAME_ENGLISH", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddlpsu", @class = "form-control" })*@

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">PSU </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">


                                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_psu, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_PSU, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlpsu", @class = "form-control" })


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Priority </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Priority", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Medium", Value = "2"},
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "3"}
                                       }, new { @id = "ddlpriority", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Duration Type </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Priority", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Short Term", Value = "1"},
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Long term", Value = "2"},
                                       }, new { @id = "ddlpriority", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Target Date </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDeadline_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Deadline Date", @required = true, @id = "Deadline_Date" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="@Model.Button" class="btn btn-success sub" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true; " />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @*}*@

                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>

    @functions{
        public string TokenHeaderValue()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }
    }
    function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/MinuteOfMeeting/MOM',
                type: "post",
              //  contentType: "application/json",
                data: { 'Description': '12345', "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }, // JSON data goes here
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>  

@model Web_App.Models.VM_MOM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MOM";
}
@*<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="min-height:560px !important; padding-bottom:20px;">

    <hr />
    <br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading" style="
    background-color: #2bbbad;
    color: white;
    font-size: 19px;"><center><b>@Model.Heading</b></center></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
                    {
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.onload = function () {
                                alert("@ViewBag.Message");
                            };
                        </script>
                    }
                    @*@{
                        IDictionary<string, object> attrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        attrs.Add("name", "TestForm");
                        attrs.Add("id", "TestForm");
                        attrs.Add("data-asynchAction", "/Home/SendMessage");
                    }*@

                    @*@using (Html.BeginForm("MOM", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {*@
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.Hidden("PaneName", null)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Task_Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Button)
                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Task Details <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5, @cols = 60, @style = "max-width:65% !important;" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Additional Comments</label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Additional_Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5, @cols = 60, @style = "max-width:65% !important;" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@

                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Review Date <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Review_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Review Date" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Review_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Weightage(%) <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">

                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weightage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Weightage" , onkeypress = "return isNumber(event)"} })

                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Task Assigned By </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-2">

                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.TaskAssignBy)

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Task Assign To <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">

                                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_js, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_JS, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "ddljs", @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem_js, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedItem_js, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                                    <br />
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_dir, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_DIR, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddldir", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_ds, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_DS, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlds", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_section_officer, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_SECTION_OFF, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlsecoff", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_psu, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_PSU, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlpsu", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_JS, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddljs", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_DIR, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddldir", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_DS, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddlds", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_SECTION_OFF, "CODE", "USER1", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddlsecoff", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CODE, new SelectList(Model.LST_PSU, "PSU_CODE", "NAME_ENGLISH", Model.CODE), new { @id = "ddlpsu", @class = "form-control" })*@

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">PSU </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">


                                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItem_psu, new MultiSelectList(Model.LST_PSU, "value", "text"), new { @id = "ddlpsu", @class = "form-control" })


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Priority </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Priority", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Medium", Value = "2"},
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "3"}
                                       }, new { @id = "ddlpriority", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Duration Type </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Priority", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Short Term", Value = "1"},
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Long term", Value = "2"},
                                       }, new { @id = "ddlpriority", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Target Date </label>

                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDeadline_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Deadline Date", @required = true, @id = "Deadline_Date" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="@Model.Button" class="btn btn-success sub" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true; " />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @*}*@

                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
@*@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/common.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/antiforgery.js"></script>
}*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    @functions{
        public string TokenHeaderValue()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }
    }
    function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({

        //    changeMonth: true,
        //    changeYear: true


        if ($('#Task_Id').val() != 0)
        {
            $('#Deadline_Date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', format: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: 0 });
        }
        else {
            $('#Deadline_Date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', format: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: 0 });
           $('#Deadline_Date').datepicker('setDate', "+7");
        }
        //});

        $('#ddlpriority').change(function ()
        {
            if($(this).val() == 1)
            {
                $('#Deadline_Date').attr("required", true);
                $('#Deadline_Date').datepicker('setDate', "+7");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#Deadline_Date').removeAttr("required");
                $('#Deadline_Date').val("");
            }

        });

        $('#Completion_Flag').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked") == true)
            {
                $('#Actual_Completion_Date').removeAttr("disabled")
            }
            else {
                $('#Actual_Completion_Date').attr("disabled", "disabled")
            }
        });
        $('#Review_Date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', format: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        // alert($('#Review_Date').val())
        //  $('#Review_Date').datepicker('setDate', new Date());



           //$('#Deadline_Date').datepicker('setDate', "+7");

           $('#Actual_Completion_Date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', format: 'dd/mm/yy' });

        //  $('#Actual_Completion_Date').datepicker('setDate', new Date());

        //$('#Review_Date').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
        $('#ddljs').multiselect({
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: '300',
            buttonWidth: '200',

            numberDisplayed: 2,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select Officer'
        });
        $('#ddldir').multiselect({
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: '300',
            buttonWidth: '200',

            numberDisplayed: 2,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select Director'
        });
        //$('#ddlds').multiselect({
        //    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
        //    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        //    enableFiltering: true,
        //    maxHeight: '300',
        //    buttonWidth: '200',

        //    numberDisplayed: 2,
        //    nonSelectedText: 'Select Under Secretary'
        //});
        //$('#ddlsecoff').multiselect({
        //    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
        //    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        //    enableFiltering: true,
        //    maxHeight: '300',
        //    buttonWidth: '200',

        //    numberDisplayed: 2,
        //    nonSelectedText: 'Select Section Officer'
        //});
        $('#ddlpsu').multiselect({
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: '300',
            buttonWidth: '400',

            numberDisplayed: 2,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select PSU'
        });
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/MinuteOfMeeting/MOM',
                type: "post",
              //  contentType: "application/json",
                data: { 'Description': '12345', "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }, // JSON data goes here
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>  

I want that when I used already used token in it it show me error
```

because when I audit this page it rchange parametr value in runtime and save it saved without any token value verfifcation.
   when I create form in mvc using beginform and antiforgery token and  also with validate antiforgery token on controller but when I save data and locally store the `_requestverificationtoken` then 
I again form the submit and replace the current token value to previous then save it it also save but when I used antiforgery tags why it is submit.

Comment: That is way too much code for us to read. Please cut it down to a [mcve].

Comment: At a high level, anti forgery tokens are designed to protect endpoints from being called by someone who lacks access to the token. Tokens are often allowed to be reused though (and there are good technical reasons for that).

Comment: but as per my audit person he said that ones i used any token it shoud expire we cannot reused that token for prevent external hit of page